# iOS Detecting whether device password lock is enabled

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm writing a Today notification center widget which I want to show different information depending on whether or not the device has password lock enabled (basically I want to hide confidential information if the device is password locked).  I looked around and couldn't find any good ways to do this.  Has anyone been able to successfully do this?

Comment: Why not have a "settings panel" where you ask whether the user wants to see that kind of information or not?

Comment: I'm planning to add that in settings as well (to give the user the option of blocking out certain info from showing in the notification area if device is locked).  But problem is the notification widget still needs a way of determining whether or not the app is locked.

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://github.com/project-imas/passcode-check)

Answer (score 2):

I would not call this best practice, but it should be a workaround:
Try to access data in the keychain. If it works, the device is free, if not it's locked.

Disclaimer: There is a chance this will break in the future with changes around WatchKit. It's not documented yet, but chances are that the watch will be able to access the keychain although the device is locked.

Comment: I think this works for regular apps, but not widgets in the 'Today' notification center.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to enable iOS Data Protection for your app and then use the `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` and `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` methods of `UIApplication` to detect changes in the password lock setting.

Warning: these API's are not intended for this use, so there's always the risk that Apple will take issue with it and reject your app.

Comment: I'll take a look.  Another issue with the Today notification widget is that the app might not be running in the background when the phone's lock state changes.  So I think I need a way to query the status on-demand when the notification area is pulled down rather than wait for events to fire from inside the main app.

Answer (score 1):

Only for iOS 8, you can use kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly protection level to find out whether or not the device is locked. This frame worked might help you out: https://github.com/liamnichols/UIDevice-PasscodeStatus

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but I tried this library before and the status is always 'LNPasscodeStatusEnabled' when trying to get the locked status from inside a today notification widget, whether or not the device is locked.  This is on iOS 8.1.2.  I'll dig into the code some more.  I imported the security framework on my widget and the shared framework targets.